# How can I recover my "unspent" bitcoin

Tags: transactions

I made a transaction since 10days ago to my Brother, But still not delivered to the receiver. It still remain "unspent" help me out on how to retrieve it.

Comment: can you provide the transaction id?

Answer (score 0):

You can make another transaction with a larger fee to override the previous one.